# В чём проблема ? Error making cache directory: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/base

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, yum

Я столкнулся с проблемой. Centos 7. Нет доступа к установке nginx и других пакетов. Директория по пути */var/cache/yum* не присутствует. Также нет доступа для создания папки *yum* в каталоге */var/cache*.

Пользователь "gent" был добавлен в группу "wheel".

Останавливал процесс `selniux`. Тоже не помогло. Но его я конфигурировать не умею. Может даже после отключения настройки доступа сохранились. Кроме того, после переключения на root `sudo su` произошла та же ошибка. Чистки кеша `yum` так же не удалась, сразу та же ошибка ниже.

Скажите, какие есть варианты?

**Обновление:**

```sh
$ ls -Z
drwx------. root root system_u:object_r:ldconfig_cache_t:s0 ldconfig
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:mandb_cache_t:s0 man
```

```sh
$ ls -l
total 4
drwx------.  2 root root   23 Apr  8  2020 ldconfig
drwxr-xr-x. 32 root root 4096 Apr  9  2020 man
```

**ОШИБКА:**

```sh
$ sudo yum install nginx Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Error making cache directory: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/base error was: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/cache/yum'
```

Comment: Ну так смотрите вывод `ls -Z` И `ls -l` На /var/cache и внутренности.

Comment: Добавил вывод. Может в настройках selniux есть изменения на директорию /var/cache/yum

Comment: Так а какие права у самого каталога _/var/cache_?

Comment: drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:var_t:s0 ----- cache
drwxr-xr-x.  5 root root   44 Aug 15 18:57 ------------cache

Answer (score 0):

На каталоге бит immutable, в чём можно убедиться при помощи команды `lsattr`.

`selinux` также можно проверить при помощи просмотра аудит - лога.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).